# What does Apple recommend for RAM usage?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, ram

What does Apple recommend for RAM usage? I ask because currently my application is using 5.8MB of the 1.0GB on an iPhone 6, the other applications I am running are using 730MB. I am only running Chrome, Calculator and Music. Does Apple have a guideline for this to prevent crashes?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann my app isn't hogging memory it's using 5.8mb I was just curious about if there was a number I should try and stay under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no such official word on this. It really depends on many things: 
what iOS version you're using (not SDK), how many applications running in background, what exact memory you're using etc.
Have look at this answer guy did some testing and post the results as follows.

- iPad1: 127MB/256MB/49% (crash amount/total amount/percentage of total)
- iPad2: 275MB/512MB/53%
- iPad3: 645MB/1024MB/62%
- iPad4: 585MB/1024MB/57%  (iOS 8.1)
- iPad Mini 1st Generation: 297MB/512MB/58%
- iPad Mini retina: 696MB/1024MB/68% (iOS 7.1)
- iPad Air: 697MB/1024MB/68%
- iPad Air 2: 1195MB/2048MB/58% (iOS 8.x)
- iPod touch 4th gen: 130MB/256MB/51% (iOS 6.1.1)
- iPod touch 5th gen: 286MB/512MB/56% (iOS 7.0)
- iPhone4: 325MB/512MB/63%
- iPhone4S: 286MB/512MB/56%
- iPhone5: 645MB/1024MB/62%
- iPhone5S: 646MB/1024MB/63%
- iPhone6: 645MB/1024MB/62% (iOS 8.x)
- iPhone6+: 645MB/1024MB/62% (iOS 8.x)
- iPhone6s: 1195MB/2048MB/58% (theoretical, untested)
- iPhone6s+: 1195MB/2048MB/58% (theoretical, untested)

If you want further details on memory management please look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/ManagingMemory.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

If you're only using 5.8 MBs than great! Google Chrome is known to be a memory hog. **Always use the least amount of RAM possible** to make sure every single user has a good experience and not just the ones with the latest hardware.